# Need help figuring out how zip(), *[...] and .update() works

Tags: python

The program is supposed to read a file and then output the frequency of N-grams. After doing some research I have figured out most of the code. The only parts that I do not understand are this: `combination= (zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(n)]))` and `c.update(combination)`. The zip function I know that it returns a list of tuples, but I do not understand why it has a for loop in its parameters.

```
from collections import Counter
filename = r'/Users/ma/desktop/dd.txt'
textfile = open(filename, 'r')

c = Counter()

def n_grams(n):
  for line in textfile:
       words = line.split()

       combination= (zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(n)]))

       c.update(combination)
  return c

n = int(raw_input('Enter the sequence of words.'))
m= n_grams(n)
```

Comment: Your title is invalid, we don't really care who give you the code and what did he ask you. Please edit it to be descriptive.

Comment: Look at how `zip`, `range`, Unpacking List https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists works in Python

Comment: @OneKitten: `zip` and `list` are actual code (Python built-ins), actually. I think Fledgling did fine with those. The whitespace in the code sample could've been handled better.

Comment: I updated the title, created a code-block instead of massive ammounts of text. I also formatted the text in the question.. I hope this represents what you wanted to ask @danilo, if not go ahead and edit to your liking but make sure you create useful content and use the title as a summary of your problem and not a sob story to lure people into reading the question, it might get on some peoples nerves :)

Comment: @Torxed Thank you very much. I am new at this, so I did not know how it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show counts "n-grams" which are sequences of `n` adjacent words in your text. For example, if the text was `"A B C D E"` and you were looking at 3-grams, you'd want to count `("A", "B", "C")`, `("B", "C", "D")` and `("C", "D", "E")` once each.

The way it does it is somewhat tricky, and it has what are probably a few bugs.

The key part is the line:

```
combination= (zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(n)]))
```

Lets tackle it from the inside out.

The inner part is a list comprehension: `[words[i:] for i in range(n)]`

The comprehension creates `n` slices of the `words` list, each skipping one more word than the previous one. The first value is the full word list, the second skips the first word, the third skips two words, and so on (up to n-1 values being skipped).

The next part is a call to `zip`, that uses a `*` in its syntax to unpack a the list created above into separate arguments. A function call like `func(*some_list)` is equivalent to `func(some_list[0], some_list[1], ...)` (where the `...` means "and so on for the rest of the list items"). It's useful syntax for calling a function with an unknown number of arguments.

So, what does the `zip` call do? `zip` takes any number of iterable arguments, and iterates over them all in parallel, taking one item from each one and packing them into a tuple, then moving on to the next.

In this specific case, the iterables are all slices of the same word list, and so you'll end up with tuples of words from the list. Because each list is offset from the previous one by one word, you end up with words that appear in sequence. These are the n-grams you're looking for!

Outside the `zip` call there's an extra set of parentheses that don't actually do anything. You should probably delete those.

Anyway, that algorithm is a somewhat complicated way to get the n-grams, though it has a certain amount of elegance to it. A more direct approach would deal with indexes and slice out the n-grams directly:

```
ngrams = [tuple(words[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(words)-n+1)]
```

I don't know if this would be faster or slower, but it seems more obvious to me what it is doing, so you may prefer it regardless.

Anyway, the final thing you asked about was the call to `update`, which the list of `n-grams` gets passed to. This is a method of `c`, a `collections.Counter` instance that is, for some reason, a global variable. `update` adds the provided n-grams to the `Counter`, which, as its name implies, counts them. If there are repeated n-grams in your text, the counts of each one will be added up in `c`.

However, it's a bit buggy that `c` is a global. If you wanted to count a different text later, you'd be out of luck, since `c` would already have the counts of the previous text in it (and so you'd get a combined count of both texts). Actually, now that I look at it, you're also taking your file object as a global variable.

You should probably create `c` in the function and pass the file object as an argument to the function, so it can be reused on different data, as necessary:

```
def n_grams(data, n): # pass the file (or some other iterable) as the data argument
    c = Counter() # create the Counter in the function

    for line in data:
        ngrams = zip(*[words[i:] for i in range(n)]) # compute the line's n-grams
        # or equivalently: [tuple(words[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(words)-n+1)]

        c.update(ngrams)   # add them to the count
    return c   # return the count at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

What `zip` does is that it joins two `lists` together in a new `list` of `tuples`.
Taken directly from the zip documentation:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

The result of `*[words[i:] for i in range(n)]` is a bit hard to visualize for you because i have no clue what the actual data is, i only know what it probably contains:

Here's an oversimplification of the code to make it more readable:

```
for line in textfile:
    words = line.split() # Splits on each <space>: 'my mom' will be ['my', 'mom']
    words_to_work_with = []
    for i in range(3):
        words_to_work_with.append(words[i:])

    combination=zip(*words_to_work_with)
    c.update(combination)
```

You loop over each line in the textfile, splitting the row into pieces (splits on <kbd>SPACE</kbd>).
Then we take words with a start-offset on that row and add it to a list like:

```
words_to_work_with = []
row = ['your', 'car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine']
words_to_work_with.append(row[0:])
words_to_work_with.append(row[1:])
words_to_work_with.append(row[2:])

words_to_work_with == [('your', 'car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine')]
```

What the last part does, is that it explodes the `list` called `words_to_work_with` by prepending `*` to it. That basically translates into:

```
zip(('your', 'car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'))
```

instead of:

```
zip([('your', 'car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine')])
```

Note the difference? The first scenario we pass 3 arguments, in the second one we send only one big list as our argument. Zip needs multiple lists to join.
The result will be a new list, with only one instance of each word in a correct order i guess.. that looks something like:

```
>>> list(zip(('your', 'car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('car', 'is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine'), ('is', 'cooler', 'than', 'mine')))
[('your', 'car', 'is'), ('car', 'is', 'cooler'), ('is', 'cooler', 'than'), ('cooler', 'than', 'mine')]
```

Comment: Why does your example use slices `row[3:]`, `row[4:]` and `row[5:]`? In the original code, they'll be `row[0:]` through `row[n-1:]`, which is rather different.

Comment: @Blckknght Because `n` in his code is not pre-defined, assumed it was `2` or something, then the outcome will be: `row[0:]` -> `row[1:]` since range(2) will generate: `0, 1`.. Or am i out on a limb here? o0

Comment: No, you're not out on a limb, that's exactly my point. You should show `words_to_work_with.append(row[0:])`, `words_to_work_with.append(row[1:])` etc, rather than the later slices only. For your example word list, there should be four 3-grams, not only the one you show at the end.

Comment: @Blckknght I'm sorry, you're correct. Got a fuzzy result from the wrong data. I rarely use zip myself, just gave it a go to explain to the OP how i thought it works, guess i should have worked with the correct data :P